# windows azure sdk localhost for node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-roles

I am running a helloworld program using node.js and windows azure sdk.

If I keep :    127.0.0.1:81

This link works and I get the hello world printed on the browser.

But when I try:

--http://192.168.1.6:81/

This link is not working. 192.168.1.6 is the localIP of the machine I am running this application.

Can you please let me know how I can get this working with a IP address

I have the node.js helloworld application from:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/

before I deploy this in cloud I want to  run my application with the IP address of the host

Answer (score 0):

The compute emulator specifically binds to 127.0.0.1 and not any other IP addresses, so there's no easy way to do this. (Workarounds like port forwarding are possible, but I wouldn't recommend doing it unless you have a good reason why you have to.)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want to test my application. for that I want to try in local environment. I really dont want to deploy. so can you please tell me what are the ways

Comment: Why don't you test by using 127.0.0.1?